# Critique: Can anyone tell me how I can improve my website?

Tags: website-design, css, critique

I am a bit rubbish at CSS and have mainly based my website off another website, in hope it would look different, although it didn't. I just want comments and tips how to change things but still keep it looking nice.

I just want advice about the [home page](http://prntscr.com/86svoc) at the moment.

[image: Homepage]

Comment: It is not that much bad. You need to take care about few details and typography. Could you tell us what you want to achieve? Seems the design is incomplete.

Comment: If you are targeting people that uses languages that writes from left to right, you may want to put the panels on the left portion of screen.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise the following:

- *Grid alignment:* Scoot your main content and top nav to the left so it lines up with "home page"
- *Content Justification:* the secondary information on the right is calling a lot of attention to itself, I would change the blue to something less eye catching, and put more color emphasis on the main content somehow. Perhaps make it not as wide, or center both columns in the middle of the page.
- *Unified illustration style:* The icon on the left is very different from the pixel style, if the pixel style is important, use it on all imagery, or have more uses of the icon style on the top left.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would be a start. Taking into account you based this website on another one and it turned out pretty much the same, you might wanna consider changing the colors and the font too.

Good luck.

PS: I took out your design on the upper right corner cause it had nothing to do with what's going on in your actual website design.

[image]